# Is there a difference in performance writing per example 2 instead 2.0 for double in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I just wondering what changes in terms of performance for writing an int instead a double for double:

double x = 2; instead double x = 2.0

Comment: There is no difference.  That conversion is compile-time syntactic sugar.  That's why it works only for integer literals and not for general `int` to `double` conversions.

Comment: there is no difference between them. for more read this article https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers

Answer (score 3):

Since this statement has to be parsed and understood by the compiler at compile time, there is no runtime benefit of one way of writing the constant number over another.

Whether your code may or may not *compile* a split-microsecond faster is not really of any interest. Write it in a way it is easy to understand for the human reader, because that is the bottleneck when working with code.